# Message 'The underlying connection was closed' when calling a WCF function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Initially, I called a function in my web service from my controller and next I paginate the result to only show 10 items in my view. I proceeded like this:

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var companies = _requestServiceClient.GetCompanies();
        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;
        var companiesListPaged = companies.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);
        return View(companiesListPaged);
    }
```

Service:

```
    public IEnumerable<Company> GetCompanies()
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            var companyRepository = unitOfWork.Create<Company>();
            return companyRepository.GetAll().MyInclude(x => x.City).ToList();
        }
    }
```

So the pagination was done after all data was retrieved from my service. It works but a lot of data was transmitted so not very efficient. I changed my code to do the pagination work directly in the service like this:

Controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;
        var companies = _requestServiceClient.GetCompaniesToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize);
        return View(companies);
    }
```

Service:

```
    public IPagedList<Company> GetCompaniesToPagedList(int PageIndex, int PageSize)
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            var companyRepository = unitOfWork.Create<Company>();
            var companies = companyRepository.GetAll().MyInclude(x => x.City).ToList();
            return companies.ToPagedList(PageIndex, PageSize);
        }
    }
```

It compiles but at runtime I got the error:

**The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.**

Any idea? Why does this change in my code gives me this error?

I didn't change anything else.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

And here is the code for the IPagedList

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    int PageCount { get; }
    int TotalItemCount { get; }
    int PageIndex { get; }
    int PageNumber { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
    bool HasPreviousPage { get; }
    bool HasNextPage { get; }
    bool IsFirstPage { get; }
    bool IsLastPage { get; }
}
```

And for ToPagedList

```
    public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int? totalCount = null)
    {
        return new PagedList<T>(source, pageIndex, pageSize, totalCount);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking if the amount of data returned by the call may exceed the limits defined in the ReaderQuotas element of your Binding.

Comment: I only return 10 items >> I don't have such problems. Thanks anyway. I think the problem is my pagination is not serializable but I don't know how to adjust. Thanks anyway.